# Line integral: $F(x,y) = (y, x^2 + y^2)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Calculate $\int_{\gamma} F(x).dx$, for $F(x,y)=(y,  x^2 + y^2)$ where $\gamma$ is th arc of circumference $\gamma(x) = (x, \sqrt{4-x^2})$ linking (-2, 0) to (0,2)

**My attempt**

$\gamma(t) = (2\cos t, 2 \sin t)$ for $t = pi$ to $ \frac{\pi}{2} $

$ \int_{\gamma} F(x).dx = - \int_{\pi / 2}^{\pi} (2 \sin t, 4(\sin ^2 t + \cos^2 t) . ( - 2 \sin t , 2 \cos t) dt = - \int_{\pi /2}^{\pi} -4 sin^2 t + 8 cost dt =8 + \pi $

The answer: $ 8 + \frac{\pi}{4} $

What I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Offhand, it looks like all you did was go from $t=3\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ when you should have gone from $t=\pi$ to $t=\pi/2$. :)

Comment: Indeed, but now I got $4 + \pi$ as answer

Comment: Well, I get the answer $8+\pi$. You made an arithmetic mistake? If you're saying the book's answer is $8+\pi/4$, I believe it's wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I got $8 + \pi$ too, I think the book is wrong, then. Thanks :)